# "End of file" when reading from standard input with an online Fortran compiler

Tags: fortran

I am running the following code via an [online Fortran compiler](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_fortran_online.php).

```
PROGRAM ONE 

IMPLICIT NONE 

REAL:: v

READ (*,*) v


IF ( sqrt(v) > 1. ) THEN
WRITE(*,*) 'At first: sqrt(v) > 1.'

ELSE IF ( sqrt(v) < 1. ) THEN 

WRITE(*,*) 'At first: sqrt(v) < 1. '
ELSE
WRITE(*,*) 'At first: sqrt(v) == 1.'
END IF 

END PROGRAM ONE
```

I get the following message.

```
$gfortran -std=gnu *.f95 -o main
$main
At line 7 of file main.f95 (unit = 5, file = 'stdin')
Fortran runtime error: End of file

Error termination. Backtrace:
#0  0x7fb0b576beda
#1  0x7fb0b576ca85
#2  0x7fb0b576d24d
#3  0x7fb0b58e3513
#4  0x7fb0b58dc459
#5  0x7fb0b58ddbb9
#6  0x400824
#7  0x4009bd
#8  0x7fb0b4c334d9
#9  0x400719
#10  0xffffffffffffffff
```

Comment: I tried declaring it using the following real:: v but i get the following message:                           
$main
At line 7 of file main.f95 (unit = 5, file = 'stdin')
Fortran runtime error: End of file

Error termination. Backtrace:
#0  0x7f1aac129eda
#1  0x7f1aac12aa85
#2  0x7f1aac12b24d
#3  0x7f1aac2a1513
#4  0x7f1aac29a459
#5  0x7f1aac29bbb9
#6  0x400824
#7  0x4009bd
#8  0x7f1aab5f14d9
#9  0x400719
#10  0xffffffffffffffff

Comment: i am speculating that there is something wrong with the online compiler i am using. (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_fortran_online.php)

Comment: "Fortran runtime error: End of file" means that you probably haven't given it the input that it expects. However, if you've made progress with that correction, then please [edit] the new program and error message into your question.

Comment: I updated the question, but no progress has been made thus far.

Comment: What do you mean by not having given the input that it expects?

Comment: Can you tell us the version of gfortran you are using, and what operating system, please?

Comment: I am using an online compiler with Mac os. As I have commented above, I am speculating that it is not very reliable. (tutorialspoint.com/compile_fortran_online.php)

Answer (score 0):

When you have a read statement like

```
READ (*,*) v
```

you may typically expect the program to pause, waiting for data from *standard input*.  However, it's possible that a normal file has been redirected to standard input, in which case the program tries to read from that file. If that file is empty, then an end-of-file condition (see your runtime error message) will occur, rather than the program waiting.

In your case, with your online compiler, there is a tab next to the source code where you can enter the data which will be used as standard input. Unless you put the input here, you will see this failure.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks a lot for the clarification. I hope that it the solution to my problem